# Without using L'Hospital Rule, evaluate $\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x}{\ln x}-\frac{1}{x \ln x}$.

Tags: calculus, limits-without-lhopital

Given Limit: $L=\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x}{\ln x}-\frac{1}{x \ln x}$
The limit reduces to $L=2$ via L'Hospital Rule
Even after employing the logarithmic limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x}=1$
Also after logarithmic series expansion $\ln (1+x) =x-\frac{x^2}{x}+\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4}{4}+...$
Couldn't attain the answer
Please explain possible algebraic manipulation or procedure to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that we have

$$\frac{x}{\log(x)}-\frac1{x\log(x)}=\frac{x+1}{x}\frac{x-1}{\log(x)}$$

and

$$\frac{x-1}{x}\le \log(x)\le x-1$$

which can be obtained using the limit definition of the exponential function along with Bernoulli's inequality as I showed in [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589429/how-to-prove-that-logxx-when-x1/1590263#1590263).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: Although trivial but since I am out of practise thus couldn't notice the formation of limit. We may even set x=t+1 for working in direct terms.

Comment: @TechnoFreak Pleased I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: set $y+1=x$ then $L=\lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac{y+1}{\ln(y+1)}-\frac{1}{(y+1) \ln(y+1)}=\lim_\limits{y\to 0} \frac{y}{\ln(y+1)}\cdot\frac{y+2}{y+1}$

Comment: And how do you evaluate the limit $\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y}{\log(y+1)}$ without L'Hospital's Rule??

Comment: @MarkViola With either the definition of the derivative of the logarithm, or the Taylor series of $\ln(1+y)$.

Comment: @J.G. And both of those are tantamount to LHR.

Comment: @MarkViola: I see your point. The OP indicated that this limit is known to him/her.

Comment: @Vasili Ah, indeed.  Good catch.

Comment: @MarkViola I disagree. L'Hôpital's rule generalizes the derivative-definition trick with the ratio of two in general nonlinear functions, while the Taylor series argument only requires computing a Maclaurin-series reciprocal to zeroth order.

Comment: @J.G. Those are tantamount, the same in kind, not equivalent.  And how does one find the derivative of the logvfunction?

Comment: @MarkViola Well, if it's _tantamount but not equivalent_ (I don't think it's even that), we've solved the problem _without_ LHR as requested. If you define $\exp x$ as the $y_0=1$ solution of $y'=y$, its inverse $\ln x$ is $\int_1^x\frac1tdt$ for $x>0$. That $\ln'x=\frac1x$ on this definition is the basis for said Taylor series.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, integral calculus is one way to proceed.  But that requires even a more advanced arsenal.  The OP is likely seeking a way forward that avoids calculus.

Comment: With whichever definition of $\ln$ is deemed calculus-free.

Comment: @J.G. As in the link I referenced, one can begin with the limit definition of the exponential function and use Bernoulli's inequality to arrive at elementary bounds for the exponential function.  Then, define the logarithm function as the inverse of the exponential function and arrive at elementary bounds for the logarithm function.  All tools are pre-calculus.  ;-)

Comment: I saw that link. It's a very lengthy strategy. If you're going to define then manipulate specific limits, you could just as easily use derivatives. You certainly needn't interpret LHR bans so broadly. Your answer may be legal given the OP's tags, but so is this one.

Answer (score 0):

One can split terms into addition by applying logarithm again:

$$L = \lim_{x \to 1}{\frac{\frac{x^2 - 1}{x}}{\ln x}} = \lim_{x \to 1}\frac{\big(1 + \frac{1}{x}\big) \cdot \big(1 - \frac{1}{x}\big)}{\ln x}$$

Taking natural log:

$$\ln{L} = \lim_{x \to 1}{\ln{\big(1 + \frac{1}{x}\big)}} + \lim_{x \to 1}{\ln\big[{\frac{\big(1 + \frac{1}{x}\big)}{\ln{x}}}}\big]$$

The rest is an exercise.

Comment: And just how does that exercise work?

Comment: @Unexpected Confusion Maybe that's a really long route and I am not sure of finding the solution with this approach. It probably may not be of much help during time contrained examinations where such limit evaluation are mere part of the main problem. Although still I am delighted that you took time to provide your way towards the solution.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$${x\over \ln x}-{1\over x\ln x}={x^2-1\over x\ln x}={2\over x}{x^2-1\over \ln(x^2)-\ln 1}$$
The limit is equal  ${2\over \ln'(1)}=2.$